# Saving frames from multiple videos in a specific location using openCV/ffmpeg and Python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract and save the first frame from multiple videos in a specific folder. For now I got the extraction part working but my saving is in BGR instead of the preferred RGB (if I am right).Although, the frames are shown in my notebook as RGB but not as BGR. Also I need to add some variable filename,because at the moment it saves the frames but keeps overwriting the same frame. Can you guys help me with the two specific problems? This is what I got so far:

SOLVED: I got the saving working, output file and colouring

```
img_rows,img_cols=200,200 

listing = os.listdir(r'C:\Users/Me\SVWnew\archery\train')

# Create a counter
counter = 0
for vid in listing:
    vid = r"C:/Users/Me/SVWnew/archery/train/"+vid
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)

    for k in range(1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        rgb =cv2.resize(frame,(img_rows,img_cols))
        plt.imshow(rgb)
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  
        plt.show()
        pathOut = r"C:/Users/Me/SVWnew - Copy/archery/train"
        cv2.imwrite(pathOut + "/frame%d.jpg" % counter, rgb) 
        counter += 1
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will solve the overwrite problem:

```
img_rows,img_cols=200,200 

listing = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\SVWnew\archery\train')

# Create a counter
counter = 0

for vid in listing:

    vid = r"C:/Users/Me/Desktop/SVWnew/archery/train/"+vid
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)

    for k in range(1):

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame=cv2.resize(frame,(img_rows,img_cols))
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        plt.imshow(rgb)
        plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  
        plt.show()

        # Create a file name 
        currentFileName = "snapshot" + str(counter) + ".jpg"

        # Save the image
        cv2.imwrite(currentFileName, rgb)

        # Increment the counter 
        counter = counter + 1 

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It is not accepting the counter in the file creation line: ---> 21         currentFileName = "snapshot" + counter + ".jpg", TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Please watch again my answer. Copy and paste the updated code and you will see that it works

Comment: I already found something else that works (see my code). Also your code seem to work too. Do you know why my frames still have the blue BGR while in my jupyter notebook they seem to be in the preferred RGB?

Comment: Can you link the BGR and the RGB versions?

Comment: How do you mean show their differences by posting a picture to both?

Comment: I thought that this line of code was coloring it back to RBG because opencv reads them as BGR: rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

Comment: Okay I found it I think. When removing this line of code. It seems to work fine! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I think the problem is that it reads it as BGR but when saving it does it in RGB (wild guess)